# Scrape / eavesdrop AJAX data using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, hook, scrape

Is it possible to use JavaScript to scrape all the changes to a webpage that is being updated live with AJAX? The site I wish to scrape updates data using AJAX every second and I want to grab all the changes. This is a auction website and several objects can change whenever a user places a bid. When a bid is placed the the following change:

The current Bid Price
The current high bidder
The auction timer has time added back to it

I wish to grab this data using a Chrome extension built on JavaScript. Is there a AJAX listener for JavaScript that can accomplish this? A tool kit? I need some direction. Can JavaScript accomplish this??

Answer (score 29):

*I'm going to show two ways of solving the problem. Whichever method you pick, don't forget to read the bottom of my answer!*

First, I present a simple method which **only works if the page uses jQuery**. The second method looks slightly more complex, but will also work on pages without jQuery.

The following examples shows how you can implement filters based on method (eg POST/GET), URL, and read (POST) data and response bodies.

### Use a global ajax event in jQuery

More information about the jQuery method can be found in the documentation of [`.ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/).
Usage:

```
jQuery.ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, ajaxOptions) {
    /* Method        */ ajaxOptions.type
    /* URL           */ ajaxOptions.url
    /* Response body */ xhr.responseText
    /* Request body  */ ajaxOptions.data
});
```

### Pure JavaScript way

When the website does not use jQuery for its AJAX requests, you have to modify the built-in `XMLHttpRequest` method. This requires more code...:

```
(function() {
    var XHR = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
    // Remember references to original methods
    var open = XHR.open;
    var send = XHR.send;

    // Overwrite native methods
    // Collect data: 
    XHR.open = function(method, url) {
        this._method = method;
        this._url = url;
        return open.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    // Implement "ajaxSuccess" functionality
    XHR.send = function(postData) {
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            /* Method        */ this._method
            /* URL           */ this._url
            /* Response body */ this.responseText
            /* Request body  */ postData
        });
        return send.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

### Getting it to work in a Chrome extension

The previously shown code has to be run in the context of the page (in your case, an auction page). For this reason, a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) has to be used which **injects (!)** the script. Using this is not difficult, I refer to this answer for a detailled explanation plus examples of usage: [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script).

### A general method

You can read the request body, request headers and response headers with the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) API. The headers can also be modified. It's however not (yet) possible to read, let alone modify the response body of a request. If you want this feature, star https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058.

Comment: If you want to share the captured XHR data with your Chrome extension's Content Script and/or background page, see [Call background function of Chrome extension from a site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777887/call-background-function-of-chrome-extension-from-a-site/13779769#13779769)

Comment: Neither of these code snippets seem to work for me (in chrome extension). Has anyone got it to work?

Comment: @K2xL Where did you put the snippet? It must be used in a script injected by a content script.

Comment: Rob: I put it in the content script. It seems like content scripts run on their own sandboxes so you can't override the XHR object through them :-(

Comment: @K2xL Please read my **whole** answer, especially the section at "Getting it to work in a Chrome extension"...

Comment: @RobW Is there a way to get this work for firefox ? I am trying out this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts ut it does not seem to work, can you help ?

Comment: @Codeanu You can also use the techniques at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879 to run content scripts in the page's context. Note that the Firefox Add-on API is much more powerful than Chrome's, consider looking in the Firefox-specific APIs to achieve this (please create a new question if you want more details on it. Of course, not before you've spent at least ten minutes on research).

Comment: @RobW, Any idea why they're killing [declarativeWebRequest](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=586636#c3) (*without concrete plans to move to stable*)?

Comment: @Pacerier The DWR API is not going to be removed yet (your linked issue is marked WontFix). However, there might be a new version of the API: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696822

Comment: I kept getting `ajaxSuccess  is not a function` [Then I read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) "As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events, including those added with the .ajaxSuccess() method, must be attached to document." So for 1.9 > you have to do `$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, ajaxOptions) { .....`