# Block and Modify AJAX requests using webRequest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension and am currently using the webrequest api. My question is simple, is it possible to block and **modify** an AJAX request with the webrequest api? If not is there a work around to this?

PS.
I am trying to inject pieces of HTML into a GMail email but the only solution I have found so far involves detecting all the various types of composes and then inject my HTML. This method is fine except its unstable, only about 70% of the time the insertion works.

If there is a better way, do let me know, thanks!

**EDIT**

Found a few alternate solutions if anyone needs it.

- Override the default `XMLHttpRequest.send` method to broadcast an event. You can modify the request before it gets sent out.
- Override the default form submit method and intercept all form submits before they are submitted (modify the form data)

Comment: Also ehre: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23561805/632951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to access or modify the response body using the webRequest api. There is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058) in chromium requesting that feature. They have recently implemented the ability of [accessing the *request* body](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91191), so there may be a chance they will also add this too.

You may have better luck with techniques that modify the `XMLHttpRequest` object, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13768794/1507998). [Here](http://izaakschroeder.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/lucidchart-javascript-breaking-limits-with-ajax-hijacking/) you have a step by step case study where the AJAX response is intercepted and modified.

Comment: I had a feeling it wasn't possible, really hope they implement it soon but thanks for the great links, should be an interesting read!

Comment: @rsanchez, But the question asker only wants to block isn't it? which is doable no?

Answer (score 2):

Although you can detect XMLHttpRequests by explicitly setting the [type property for chrome.webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#types) to `xmlhttprequest`, you will only be able to block asynchronous requests.

Synchronous XMLHttpRequests made from your extension are hidden from blocking event handlers in order to prevent deadlocks. Also the webRequest API will only expose calls that are made to URi patterns defined in the [permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/permissions.html) area of your manifest.

Comment: Right, I already am blocking requests from mail.google.com, specifically XMLHttpRequests as you stated. However is it possibly to modify the responseBody of these requests with webrequest? I have tried and it does not seem to be something that is supported.

Comment: It is my understanding that you can only modify the responseHeaders object using the blocking method. There is a pending feature request for exactly the sort of control you want https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058

Comment: The key part is "Synchronous XMLHttpRequests **made from your extension**", so you can process synchronous XHRs from other origins. And the question makes it clear that it's page's own requests.