# Intercept AJAX responses in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, intercept

We're building a chrome extension on top of an existing system, to help with a few tasks.

It's AJAX intense and it would be far more efficient than scraping html and triggering events to intercept some of the AJAX responses.

Example: Frome chrome console, networks tab, you see the beautiful JSON:
[image]

How can a Chrome Extension get to that JSON ?

I've tried [WebRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) but it appear it does't allow to do this.

Comment: Why do you say that WebRequest doesn't help with that? Please expand on that.

Comment: Also, your question as of now is under risk of being closed as "opinion-based". Instead of broadly asking for a "de facto way", please include more specific details about your task.

Comment: So what is exactly meant by "intercept"? Please describe the normal workflow of the system, and how you want to modify that.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't mind using **jQuery**, you can use the

```
$.ajaxComplete( function( Event event, jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject ajaxOptions ))
```

method on the document.

In the callback you can grab all of the information about any of the events and log them accordingly.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Comment: This will not work, at least not without a lot of modification. The extension lives in a separate context.

Comment: If it's a chrome extension, isn't window the same context? $(window).ajaxComplete(). It is working in my extension sanbox

Comment: Content scripts live in a [separate context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) from the page, and executing this without additional techniques will lead to intercepting only AJAX calls 1) made from extension context, 2) made with jQuery.

Comment: See the duplicate target; Rob W explains it in detail.

Comment: Got ya, I don't have much experience with extensions, just used this when we needed to intercept 3rd party ajax calls on our site. Thanks for clearing up

Comment: Then what will be solution for this.