# Chrome Extension - Save buffered data of a youtube video

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I've been trying to save the buffered data of a youtube video locally as to allow offline viewing of that part.

The [WebRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) API would've been perfect, but it doesn't expose the response body. I've also tried capturing the XHR of the webpage like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765031/scrape-eavesdrop-ajax-data-using-javascript/13768794#13768794) but for some reason it only captures the POST requests.

Is this something possible to achieve ?

Thanks.

Comment: Such an extension is probably against the [Chrome Web Store TOS](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/terms). 4.4.1 _You agree that you will not engage in any activity with the Web Store, including the development or publication of Products or other materials, that violates the Google Chrome Web Store Program Policies, or that_ 6) _enables the unauthorized download of streaming content or media_

Comment: @abraham I understand this is against their TOS, but you don't have to upload it to the web store, there are other methods of publishing your extension.

Comment: [Not really anymore](http://www.theverge.com/2013/11/7/5077856/google-for-windows-to-prohibit-browser-extensions-not-in-chrome-web-store).

Comment: @abraham I'm aware of that, but it only affects Windows users. Also you can use ‘Load unpacked extension’. Anyway that's not the point, I do it mainly as a hobby, so it doesn't matter if I couldn't publish it.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you were aware of the risks.